# Not all x labels are being shown on geom_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a df similar to the one below:

```
df <- 
structure(list(Month = c(201701, 201702, 201703, 201704, 201705, 201706, 
                       201707, 201708, 201709, 201710, 201711, 201712, 
                       201801, 201802, 201803, 201804, 201805, 201806, 
                       201807, 201808, 201809, 201810, 201811, 201812), 
             Category = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                    4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
                                    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), 
                                  .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 
                                  class = "factor"), 
             Percentage = c(0.46, 0.47, 0.14, 0.42, 0.32, 0.26, 0.37, 
                            0.07, 0.33, 0.35, 0.23, 0.36, 0.47, 0.13, 
                            0.23, 0.47, 0.49, 0.06, 0.24, 0.28, 0.45, 
                            0.07, 0.49, 0.47)), 
        class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

**Month**: on the following format ("201701", "201702", (...), "201805")

**Category**: ("A", "B", "C", etc)

**Percentage**: ("0.01", "0.03", "0.06", etc)

When I plot it as:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Month, y = Percentage, color = Category)) +
  geom_line() + scale_x_continuous()
```

It returns only 3 labels for the x  axis, and they've been changed from the original dataset.

Does anybody know how to show all labels, and on the original format?

Thanks!

Comment: instead of using unnecessary bold letters, provide reproducible sample data, e.g. pasting output of `dput(df)` here.

Comment: Your `Month` column is `numeric` but the process doesn't understand that there's a specific format like `2017-01`, etc. And numbers like `201720, 201750, 201780` are valid `numeric` values between `min` and `max` of `Month` and the process automatically uses them as breaks/labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform your Month-column into a proper date column and then plot it. Then you get a x-axis on a date scale and ordered how you would expect it.

```
df$Month <- as.Date(paste0(df$Month, "01"), format = "%Y%m%d")

ggplot(df, aes(x = Month, y = Percentage, color = Category)) +
  geom_line()
```

You then can even modify the breaks and look of you x-axis with `scale_x_date`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Month, y = Percentage, color = Category)) +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months", date_labels = "%Y%m")
```

[image]

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- 
  structure(list(Month = c(201701, 201702, 201703, 201704, 201705, 201706, 
                           201707, 201708, 201709, 201710, 201711, 201712, 
                           201801, 201802, 201803, 201804, 201805, 201806, 
                           201807, 201808, 201809, 201810, 201811, 201812), 
                 Category = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                        4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
                                        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), 
                                      .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 
                                      class = "factor"), 
                 Percentage = c(0.46, 0.47, 0.14, 0.42, 0.32, 0.26, 0.37, 
                                0.07, 0.33, 0.35, 0.23, 0.36, 0.47, 0.13, 
                                0.23, 0.47, 0.49, 0.06, 0.24, 0.28, 0.45, 
                                0.07, 0.49, 0.47)), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful answer and for creating a mock df for clarification! I'll edit my post so that it is useful for other users who might have the same problem (still new to the forum, apologies for the inexperience).

Answer (score 1):

this should work for displaying all values On X-axis,if this doesn't work then provide the sample dataset using `dput(df)`

```
scale_x_continuous("Month",as.character(Month), breaks = Month)
```